# Elasticsearch DocumentSimilarity dense_vector got multiple values for argument 'body'

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to store Document Vectors in an Elasticsearch index in order to calculate document similarity. I'm using the Python client for Elasticsearch 7.8.0.

I have a (dummy) Elasticsearch index with the following mapping:

```
mapping = {
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "title_vector":{
                "type": "dense_vector",
                "dims": 3
            }
        }
    }
}
   
es.indices.create(index="test_vector", body=mapping)
```

And I stored a bunch of vectors in the following way:

```
vectors = [[1,2,3],[2,2,2],[1,2,2],[2,2,2],[4,5,6],[1,1,1]]

for i, v in enumerate(vectors):
    doc = {"title_vector": v}
    es.create("test_vector", id=i, body=doc)
```

According to the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/query-dsl-script-score-query.html#vector-functions), my query to get the most similar documents, should be as follows:

```
doc = {
    "query": {
    "script_score": {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "script": {
            "source": "cosineSimilarity(params.queryVector, 'title_vector') + 1.0",
            "params": {
                "queryVector": [1,1,1]
            }
        }
    }
}}

es.search("test_vector", body=doc)
```

But I'm getting

```
TypeError: search() got multiple values for argument 'body'
```

It seems more like a Python error than an Elastic error. But I can't really find the cause of the error and how I should structure my query differently in order to solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: added Elasticsearch version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it is a python error. So below is how the `es.search` is defined according to this [link](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.search)

```
search(body=None, index=None, params=None, headers=None)
```

As you see the first parameter is `body`.

Notice the `es.search` you have, you haven't specified the `key` in the first parameter i.e. `body, index, params, headers`. As a result, python interprets that as value for `body` according to the above method declaration.

Just add `index="test_vector"` instead of just `"test_vector"` in the first parameter and that should do the trick.

```
es.search(index="test_vector", body=doc)
```

Hope it helps!